# Static values vs passing parameters

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I have to pass a `List<>` across 2-3 independent classes up and down the class. Right now I'm mostly passing the list using parameter so all 3 classes gets the list. Should I use a static list instead of passing List all over the classes to simplify the code like `Class23.ListObjects.Add()` and then release the static values once the operation is done so the next operation starts with an empty List. Right now it feels like the parameters are getting a lot and I'm getting confused if the list has the right values, forgetting to pass the list to the next class, etc. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you create a new class that represents the combined operation performed by the various classes (a "context" class, if you will).  Values needed to perform the operation can be held as instance variables in that context, along with instances of the classes used in performing the work.

That way, you avoid passing stuff around (as code evolves, this can get somewhat ugly) while avoiding a "global" variable.  Data is in exactly the scope it needs to be, and is disposed when the overall operation is complete.

Comment: the context concept abstraction sounds reasonable here, although I am not quite sure what is the exact question, but I don't think the static member is good practice.

Comment: @zinking: Agree, there are few (but some) instances where `static` is the best choice.  Doesn't feel right to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

In Coding practices, it is bad to have static or Global variables and passing through parameters is considered good.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a static parameter, you run the risk of getting corrupted data if those functions are used in multiple places in your code, especially if threading is involved.

For instance, suppose Class A needs to use your functions that act on your static list.  Before those functions are completed, Class B tries to use them as well, causing the list to get data from both calls, since the same static list is used in both cases.